# Assembly.Load 3 dlls

Tags: c#

I have 3 dlls loaded to resourses. They are switched as Embedded resources.
I have such code which loads only one dll to Assembly.
How to load all dlls?

```
public partial class Main : Form
{
    public Main()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += AssemblyResolve;
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public static Assembly AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()[3]))
        {
            if (stream == null)
                return null;

            byte[] rawAssembly = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(rawAssembly, 0, (int)stream.Length);  
            return Assembly.Load(rawAssembly);
        }
    }
```

Comment: this might help: during compilation, emedded resources are named "projectname.foldername[.morefoldernames].filename.ext" though, I generally wouldn't ever recommend embedding assemblies. You'd need a really good reason to not copy them to the output folder and load them normally.

Comment: Please do not deface your own questions. If you soved your problem on your own without the help of any of the answers you are supposed to post your own answer to the question. You then can accept that answer after 2 days (Please do so, if you don't your question will keep getting auto promoted to the front page as a question with no accepted answer)

Answer (score 2):

You're calling index 3 (Strangely it doesn't fail as you have 3 dll's they should be placed at [0][1][2]. Perhaps because you have a resource apart from the dlls? Anyways you can just do a simple loop.

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) // Your dll's seem to be stored from index 1
    using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()[i]))
        {
            if (stream == null)
                return null;

            byte[] rawAssembly = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(rawAssembly, 0, (int)stream.Length);  
            return Assembly.Load(rawAssembly);
        }
```

That should do it